# ReactJS.net unable to debug

Tags: asp.net-core, reactjs, reactjs.net

I've created a small app using ReactJS.Net and ASP.NET 5.  If I render a component serverside using `@Html.React` and tie that to the MVC

```
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using React.AspNet
@model Models.DashboardViewModel

@Html.React("MessageBoard", new
{
    recentPosts = Model.RecentPosts
})
```

messageBoard.jsx

```js
"use strict";

var MessageBoard = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (<table className="table forum table-striped">
                <thead> 
                    <tr>
                        <th className="cell-stat"></th>
                        <th>Topic</th>
                        <th className="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm">Replies</th>
                        <th className="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.recentPosts.map(function(boardPost){
                            return <BoardPostRow post={boardPost}/>;
                        }, this)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>)
        }
});
```

This all works great.  The problem is that when I go to sources, there is no .js file so I have no way to debug.  This is probably ok for some simple read-only elements.  But now I want to render some interactive elements that contain state, a form for creating a new Post to the "message board".  Here's the code in the same *.cshtml file.

```
<div id="newPost"></div>

@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/Components/Board/boardPostForm.jsx")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/Components/Common/textInput.jsx")"></script>
    <script>React.render(BoardPostForm({}), document.getElementById("newPost"))</script>
    @Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
}
```

The error I get in the console is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
textInput.jsx:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
(index):69 Uncaught ReferenceError: BoardPostForm is not defined(anonymous function) @ (index):69
(index):70 [.NET] Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of MessageBoard. See http://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
(index):71 [.NET] Warning: Unknown DOM property class. Did you mean className?
(index):71 Uncaught ReferenceError: MessageBoard is not defined
```

It seems an error trying to read the .jsx, because it takes me to the render function when I click on the error.  What am I missing here?  Maybe I need to do the jsx->js conversion as part of my build process (I am using Gulp) instead of relying on ReactJS.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you hit `/scripts/Components/Board/boardPostForm.jsx` in your web browser? It should show the compiled JSX and have some ReactJS.NET info at the top of the file. If it doesn't, make sure the `*.jsx` handler is configured in your `Web.config`. It should look something like this:

```
<add name="ReactJsx" verb="GET" path="*.jsx" type="React.Web.JsxHandlerFactory, React.Web" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

> What am I missing here? Maybe I need to do the jsx->js conversion as part of my build process (I am using Gulp) instead of relying on ReactJS.NET?

You can use Gulp if you like, up to you. I have a sample here that uses Webpack for bundling, and ReactJS.NET for server-side rendering: https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/tree/master/src/React.Sample.Webpack

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using ASP.NET 5 so there is no web config.  If I go to the .jsx file I am seeing it in uncompiled format.  Thanks for the quick response, I'll take a look at your sample.

Comment: I'm now compiling to .js as part of my build process... I don't understand however why I need both the <script src=@Url.content... and the @app.UseReact(config => config.AddScript('...??  It seems I can comment out the <script part in my view but then I can no longer use javascript breakpoints.  If I comment out the config.AddScript part I get an error that an element is not defined.  Doesn't make much sense that I have to add every react component reference in two places (I'd rather just use require where I need it but even then I get an error 'require is not defined')

Comment: I am getting a similar error when i try and perform server side rendering. I receive an uncaught reference error workstation is not defined for the following: <script>ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Workstation, {"documentList":""}), document.getElementById("react1"));

Comment: I was following the example on the reactjs.net tutorial page and was placing my jsx file in the bundle config and including the bundle ref in my view page. This did not work for me. It only worked with out error when i specifically referenced the jsx file using a script tag in my view page

Comment: @Daniel Lo Nigro - Is this supposed to recompile on develop?

Comment: @monkeyjumpsSounds like you're not loading the "Workstation" component client-side. You need to load the JavaScript client-side too, unless you explicitly render the component *only* server-side.

Comment: @ovatsug25 Depends on what you're doing. If you're using Webpack or similar, you'd need to use Webpack's watch mode. ReactJS.NET automatically reloads the built JS file on page load.  If you're just using the JSX files directly, ReactJS.NET will automatically reload them when you modify them.